# How to display firebase multiple path information in a single Angular page?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a simple database like this:

```
{
  "groups": {
    "123": {
      "name": "developers",
      "users": {
        "1": true
      },
      "users_count": 1
    }
  },
  "events": {
    "456": {
      "name": "Developers conference",
      "users": {
        "1": true
      },
      "users_count": 1
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "1": {
      "name": "Jon",
      "groups": {
        "123": true
      },
      "events": {
        "456": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the user's homepage, I want to display all the information about the groups and events, such as their names. So, in the `Homepage` class, i'm doing this:

After getting the user's information, I check if it has a group or event. If so, I get the `key` of each one, `subscribe()` to the group or event using the `key` and add the data to an array after it is loaded.

```
export class HomePage {

  user: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  groupsKey: Array<any>;
  groups: Array<any> = [];

  eventsKey: Array<any>;
  events: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(private _auth: AuthService, public afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {

    this.user = this.afDB.object(`/users/${this._auth.uid}`);
    this.user.subscribe(user =>{

      if(user.groups){
        this.groupsKey = Object.keys(user.groups); 
        this.groupsKey.forEach(key => {
          let groupObservable = this.afDB.object(`/groups/${key}`);
          groupObservable.subscribe(group => {
            this.groups.push(group);
          })
        })
      }

      if(user.events){
        this.eventsKey = Object.keys(user.events);
        this.eventsKey.forEach(key => {
          let eventObservable = this.afDB.object(`/events/${key}`);
          eventObservable.subscribe(event => {
            this.events.push(event);
          })
        })
      }

    })
  }
}
```

In the HTML part:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of groups">
  {{item.name}}: {{item.users_count}} users
</div>
```

This approach works at first sight, but when some update is made in a group or event, a duplicate is pushed in the array, going back to normal when the page is reloaded.

What can be a better implementation in this case? I know that I should remove the arrays and use the `async` pipe, but couldn't figure out how to  do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumble upon with this answer with the same question I had, here's my solution:

I got rid of static arrays and used only `Observables` and its operators.

```
export class HomePage {

  user: FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
  groups: Observable<Array<{}>>;
  events: Observable<Array<{}>>;

  constructor(private _auth: AuthService, public afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {

    this.user = this.afDB.object(`/users/${this._auth.uid}`);
    this.user.subscribe(user =>{

      if(user.groups){
        this.groups = Observable.of(user.groups)
        .map(obj => {
          let arr = [];
          Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) =>{
           //get an Observable containing the info for each key in user.groups object.
            arr.push(this.afDB.object(`groups/${key}`)); 
          })
          //zip() all Observables in the array
          let zip = Observable.zip(...arr);

          //return the emitted values (will return an Observable)
          return zip;
        })
        //use switchMap() to flatten the Observables
        .switchMap(val => val)
      }

      if(user.events){
        this.events = Observable.of(user.events)
        .map(obj => {
          let arr = [];
          Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) =>{
            arr.push(this.afDB.object(`events/${key}`)); 
          })
          let zip = Observable.zip(...arr);
          return zip;
        })
        .switchMap(val => val)
      }

    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> I know that I should remove the arrays and use the  async pipe, but couldn't figure out how to do this.

This is how I do it when I want the page to listen for changes from the DB.
I use `Arrays` like you - when I actually don't need to observe, just a list of things ...

```
.ts
-----
groupsObservable : Observable<any[]>;
eventsObservable : Observable<any[]>;

loadGroups() {
  this.groupsObservable = this.afDB.list("groups/").valueChanges();
}

loadEvents() {
  this.eventsObservable = this.afDB.list("events/").valueChanges();
}

.html
------
<div *ngFor="let g of groupsObservable | async">
  {{ g.name }} 
</div>

<div *ngFor="let e of eventsObservable | async">
  {{ e.name }} 
</div>
```